# Only render recent changes Firestore + Angular Chat app

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I have a created a chat app using firestore(using angularfire wrapper) and angular and it's working. The database structure is like this. I have unique ids for every user. When ever someone(sender) sends a message to other person(receiver) I add the message to sender:

```
collection("messages") => doc(sender's ID) => collection(receiver's ID) => doc(message ID)
```

Also, I add the same message to receiver:

```
collection("messages") => doc(receiver's ID) => collection(sender's ID) => doc(message ID)
```

Now, When user(sender) opens a chat with another user(receiver) I attach listener(valueChanges) to:

```
collection("messages") => doc(sender ID) => collection(receiver ID)
```

each message in the collection is structured like this:

```
message: 'string message'
profilePic: 'url for profile pic'
senderId: 'unique id of sender'
timestamp: some timestamp
```

Everything works as expected with this configurations but there are a few problems.

1. Whenever a new message is added the the 'valueChanges' listens for the changes and assigns the value to array 'chats'. 'chats' array is used with *ngFor to display the content of messages. Problem occurs when ever I receive changes, the whole list of messages are re-rendered including the profile pics. Ideally, only the most recent changes should be rendered.
2. There is no way (or that i can think of) to query for most recent message from every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `valueChanges` would be simple, but you will see the problems and it also costs of DB usage. So I recommend you to have a look at [snapshotChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges).

You could separate the logic as following way.

- Load all messages at the entry time using `valuechanges` and `first`/or `take(1)` operator.

```
this.messages = await this.afs.collection('messages')
  .valuechanges()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .toPromise();
```

- And you have to listen the recent changes and modify the array in the Angular side.

```
// manage recently added messages
this.afs.collection('messages').snapshotChanges(['added'])
  .pipe(takeUntil(untilFn))
  .subscribe(added => {
    this.messages = [...added, this.messages];
});

// manage recently removed messages
this.afs.collection('messages').snapshotChanges(['removed'])
  .pipe(takeUntil(untilFn))
  .subscribe(removed => {});

// manage recently modified messages
this.afs.collection('messages').snapshotChanges(['modified'])
  .pipe(takeUntil(untilFn))
  .subscribe(modified => {});
```

Please note the return type of `snapshotChanges` is different than `valueChanges`.